# Blackberry Package project issue -1.debug

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm using BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.1.2.201003212304-12 (BB 5 SO).

When i rich click project -> BlackBerry -> Package Project its, generates some files on my deliverable folder. This files are the one u use to put the App on the web so my client can download the app and install it on his BlackBerry.

Now i'm facing a problem, some times, its create a file that prevent me install the app on BB. this file is ProjectName-1.debug.

What is making this error is why i am here. I don't know why this is happening.

My code that works fine:

```
public void agendar(){
    String msg = "asdasd";      
    boolean seguir = true;
    if(_cedula.getText() == null){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _fechaNac.getDate() < 1){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _tel.getText() == null){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _pnombre.getText() == null ){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _papellido.getText() != null){
        seguir = false;
    }
    int i = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK, msg);
}
```

Same code with one line that makes the "error":

```
public void agendar(){
    String msg = "asdasd";      
    boolean seguir = true;
    if(_cedula.getText() == null){
        seguir = false;
        msg = " xxx ";
    }
    if(seguir && _fechaNac.getDate() < 1){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _tel.getText() == null){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _pnombre.getText() == null ){
        seguir = false;
    }
    if(seguir && _papellido.getText() != null){
        seguir = false;
    }
    int i = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK, msg);
}
```

The only difference is the line msg = " xxx ".

The components im using are BasicEditField and one DateField.

Also if i add this

```
int i = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK, "aaaaaaaaa asdasd ");
```

the package get corrupted.

Yesterday, i created a new class in the project and just that was enough to corrupt the package.

So far, i re installed the eclipse plugin, and nothing changed. I can't fine any reference to this problem on google. Im stuck here with this and i dont know what else to check. On the simulator its works fine.

What is making this happening? What does -1.debug mean? When i try to install the app it looks for -1.cod file.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on the Official BlackBerry Java Forum:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blackberry-Package-project-issue-1-debug/td-p/2508105

As requested, here are the important details from the linked post:

There is no corruption, what is happening here is that your project has got large enough to exceed the limits of a single cod, and so the project is being built into multiple cods.

Typically you don't see that, because the build process zips up the individual cods, and puts them all in one large cod.  However the debug-n files are a good indication that you exceeded one cod file - these are always kept separate and there is a debug-n file for each cod file.

So take your single file ".cod", rename it to ".zip", and then open the zip file.  You will probably see 2 cods in there.

Unzip this and put the multiple cod files on the web site for download.  If you check the jad file that has been created, you will see that it lists multiple cods.

If you want to read more about this, search the BlackBerry forum for 'sibling'.  The multiple cod files are generally referred as sibling cod files.

Also see here for more on this:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-7-or-earlier-smartphone/ta-p/1300209